# The event handler '' could not be found for appending statements

Tags: silverlight

I am attempting to bind a control (any control) to my SQL database using a RIA service following the video located here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZSDKPjRsDI4.

After creating the Data Source, when I try to use the UI to drag and drop a control from the Data Sources window to a blank Design window, I get this error in a popup dialog:

*The event handler '' could not be found for appending statements.*

Interestingly, I searched and did not find any reference whatsoever to this error.

The design surface then  turns into this message:

```
System.ArgumentException
Width and Height must be non-negative.
   at System.Windows.Size..ctor(Double width, Double height)
   at MS.Internal.Designer.Viewport.ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.ArrangeCore(Rect finalRect)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Arrange(Rect finalRect)
   at System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayout()
   at System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayoutCallback(Object arg)
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.InvokeOnRenderCallback.DoWork()
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.FireInvokeOnRenderCallbacks()
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandlerCore(Object resizedCompositionTarget)
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandler(Object resizedCompositionTarget)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
```

Comment: Are there Width and Height properties that contain negative values for the size of a control?

Comment: Yeah, I figured it out.  I needed to change the query for the DomainService class, that was demonstrated in the video, but I mistakenly thought it was optional.  Apparently the default query returned no (or wrong) info which resulted in the error.  Thanks.